# Dropzone.js maxFilesize not working

Tags: dropzone.js

Trying to upload files that are 3MB and greater with Dropzone, but it isn't working for me even though I specified a maxFilesize of 500MB. Tried looking at other answers but they didn't work for me.

Here is what I have for the HTML:

```
<form id="dropzone" action="photoupload.php" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form><br />
```

Here is what I have for the Javascript:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 500,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    init: function() {
        this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
            console.log("File progress", progress);
        });
    }
  }
```

The script is working for the acceptedFiles part (rejecting all non-images), but won't upload files larger than 2 to 3 MB, and I'm clueless as to why.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you are trying to upload file bigger than 3MB? Also the default maxFilesize is 500MB so you don't need to specify that

Comment: Nothing happens, the file just doesn't get uploaded to the folder. Small files and icons get uploaded, but regular/large pictures don't.

Comment: Do you see the upload progress? Or is the file just not viewed?

Comment: i think is PHP the issue here. check your php.ini

Answer (score 5):

I think you need this:

```
Dropzone.prototype.accept = function(file, done) {
      if (file.size > this.options.maxFilesize * 1024 * 1024 ) {
        return done(this.options.dictFileTooBig.replace("{{filesize}}", Math.round(file.size / 1024 / 10.24) / 100).replace("{{maxFilesize}}", this.options.maxFilesize));
      } else if (!Dropzone.isValidFile(file, this.options.acceptedFiles)) {
        return done(this.options.dictInvalidFileType);
      } else if ((this.options.maxFiles != null) && this.getAcceptedFiles().length >= this.options.maxFiles) {
        done(this.options.dictMaxFilesExceeded.replace("{{maxFiles}}", this.options.maxFiles));
        return this.emit("maxfilesexceeded", file);
      } else {
        return this.options.accept.call(this, file, done);
      }
    };
```

Comment: where should I put this code? I have the same problem with TS but only when the dropzone is loaded in a sub-html when using tinymce's jbimages plugin..

Answer (score 3):

Without further information I assume that the problem is related to your server. Obviously Dropzone can not control your server configuration, which often have filesize upload limitations as well.

In your case (PHP) the configuration options in question are `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Please refer to the question "[How to change the maximum upload file size in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)?" for more information on how to change those options.